# what is the point of using the UUID tool in pimcore?

Tags: pimcore

What is the point of using the UUID tool in pimcore?

I'm a symfony developer, and used to work with uuid's for all my entities but with pimcore there is always a integer ID present.

Is the uuid used in the graphql api?

Please give your best advice why/why-not to use the uuid-tool.